# Django - poll - listing choices based on login user detail

Tags: django

Hy,

I created a poll and the page of the poll can be accesed only if the user have a magiclink(made with django-sesame). After open that page using that maginlink i know witch user is, because when link is generated it incorporate the user information and include in that link.

The obtions/choices (*participanti*) of the poll contain name and departemnt (*dep_participant*)field/value. The users also has and departemnt value (*departament*).

So, the issue/question : in that page o the poll i want to show the name and departemnt for all obtions/choices (*participanti*)  exept the obtions/choices (*participanti*) with the same department as the login user. I don't know how to make the query in view or forloop in template with that rule.

With another words: if the user logged in is from department "hr" i want to show in the template all the choices/options from that poll for all department except those from "hr". Please help me with a solution. Thank you

Below find my settings

users models.py

```
class UserVot(AbstractUser):
    departament = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    rol = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

poll models.py

```
class Campanie(models.Model):
.....

class Participanti(models.Model):
    campanievot = models.ForeignKey(Campanie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nume_participant = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='nume')
    dep_participant = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='departament')
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nume_participant

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Participanti'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Participanti'
```

views.py

```
@authenticate
def votare_campanie(request):

    campanie = get_object_or_404(Campanie)
 
    try:
        participant_votat = campanie.participanti_set.get(pk=request.POST['participanti'])
       

    except (KeyError, Participanti.DoesNotExist):
      
        return render(request, 'campanievot/campanie.html', {
            'campanie' : campanie,
            'error_message' : "Trebuie sa votezi cel putin un coleg",
        })
    else:
        participant_votat.votes += 1
        participant_votat.save()
 
        messages.success(request, "Multumim pentru feedback!")
        return redirect('campanievot:index')
```

template.html

```
<form action=" {% url 'campanievot:votare_campanie' %} " method="post" >
                {% csrf_token %}

                {% for p in campanie.participanti_set.all %}

               <label for="p{{ forloop.counter }}" class="form-check custom-icon mt-2 mb-4" role="button">
                    <input type="radio" name="participanti" class="form-check-input" id="p{{ forloop.counter }}"
                        value="{{ p.id }}">
                    <span class="form-check-label">
                        <span class="content">
                            <span for="p{{ forloop.counter }}" class="heading mb-1 d-block lh-1-25">{{p.nume_participant }} {{ p.dep_participant }}</span>
                            <!-- <span class="d-block text-small text-muted">04.05.2021 - 12:00 </span> -->
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </label>

                {% endfor %}
                {{form.media}}
            
                <button class="m-auto btn btn-icon btn-icon-start btn-primary mb-1" type="submit">
                    <i data-acorn-icon="send"></i>
                    <span>Trimite</span>
                </button>
            </form>
```

I try to in view with

```
try:
        participant_votat = campanie.participanti_set.get(pk=request.POST['participanti']).exclude(participanti__dep_participant=request.uservot.departament)
```

but is not warking, it show all the obtions/choices
Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution. In the template i set a "if" statement like this

```
{% for p in campanie.participanti_set.all %}

                {% if p.dep_participant == request.user.departament %}

                {% else %}

               <label for="p{{ forloop.counter }}" class="form-check custom-icon mt-2 mb-4" role="button">
                    <input type="radio" name="participanti" class="form-check-input" id="p{{ forloop.counter }}"
                        value="{{ p.id }}">
                    <span class="form-check-label">
                        <span class="content">
                            <span for="p{{ forloop.counter }}" class="heading mb-1 d-block lh-1-25">{{p.nume_participant }} {{ p.dep_participant }}</span>
                            <!-- <span class="d-block text-small text-muted">04.05.2021 - 12:00 </span> -->
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </label>

                {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}
                {{form.media}}
```